# Build a Where clause using a loop and concatening each iterarion with an OR

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a list of N pairs of integers, e.g.:

```
2, 4
5, 7
9, 10
11, 12
```

And I need to build a query like:

```
WHERE 
    (foo = 2 AND bar = 4) OR
    (foo = 5 AND bar = 7) OR
    (foo = 9 AND bar = 10) OR
    (foo = 11 AND bar = 12)
```

If it was a constant length list, I could write something like:

```
var query = myClass.Where(x =>
    (foo == values[0][0] && bar == values[0][1]) ||
    (foo == values[1][0] && bar == values[1][1]) ||
    (foo == values[2][0] && bar == values[2][1]) ||
    (foo == values[3][0] && bar == values[3][1]));
```

But the length of the list varies, and I am looking for a way to create the query using a loop.

I found I can use `Queryable.Union()` for a similar result, but considering there are more conditions in the query, and the list of pairs can be long, I would prefer to avoid the *union*.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: Have you checked out http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this problem based on a similar solution described at [Dynamic Queries in Entity Framework using Expression Trees](http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/37/dynamic-queries-in-entity-framework-using-expression-trees)

Here is the solution.

First, a class to hold a *foo* and *bar* pair:

```
public class FooBarPair
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the collection of *foos* and *bars*:

```
var pairs = new FooBarPair[]
{
    new Foo() { Foo = 10537, Bar = 1034 },
    new Foo() { Foo = 999, Bar = 999 },
    new Foo() { Foo = 888, Bar = 888 },
    new Foo() { Foo = 10586, Bar = 63 },
};
```

And here is the code that builds the query expression:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> whereClause =
        BuildOrExpressionTree<MyClass, int>(pairs, m => m.Foo + m.Bar);

    var myClasss = model.Set<MyClass>();
    IQueryable<MyClass> query = myClasss.Where(whereClause);
}

/// <summary>
/// Starts a recursion to build WHERE (m.Foo = X1 AND m.Bar = Y1) [OR (m.Foo = X2 AND m.Bar = Y2) [...]].
/// </summary>
private static Expression<Func<TValue, bool>> BuildOrExpressionTree<TValue, TCompareAgainst>(
    IEnumerable<FooBarPair> wantedItems,
    Expression<Func<TValue, TCompareAgainst>> convertBetweenTypes1)
{
    ParameterExpression inputParam1 = convertBetweenTypes1.Parameters[0];

    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = convertBetweenTypes1.Body as BinaryExpression;

    Expression binaryExpressionTree = BuildBinaryOrTree<FooBarPair>(
        wantedItems.GetEnumerator(),
        binaryExpression.Left,
        binaryExpression.Right,
        null);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue, bool>>(binaryExpressionTree, new[] { inputParam1 });
}

/// <summary>
/// Recursive function to append one 'OR (m.Foo = X AND m.Bar = Y)' expression.
/// </summary>
private static Expression BuildBinaryOrTree<T>(
    IEnumerator<FooBarPair> itemEnumerator,
    Expression expressionToCompareTo1,
    Expression expressionToCompareTo2,
    Expression prevExpression)
{
    if (itemEnumerator.MoveNext() == false)
    {
        return prevExpression;
    }

    ConstantExpression fooConstant = Expression.Constant(itemEnumerator.Current.Foo, typeof(int));
    ConstantExpression barConstant = Expression.Constant(itemEnumerator.Current.Bar, typeof(int));

    BinaryExpression fooComparison = Expression.Equal(expressionToCompareTo1, fooConstant);
    BinaryExpression barComparison = Expression.Equal(expressionToCompareTo2, barConstant);

    BinaryExpression newExpression = Expression.AndAlso(fooComparison, barComparison);

    if (prevExpression != null)
    {
        newExpression = Expression.OrElse(prevExpression, newExpression);
    }

    return BuildBinaryOrTree<FooBarPair>(
        itemEnumerator,
        expressionToCompareTo1,
        expressionToCompareTo2,
        newExpression);
}
```

Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3):

You can perform one trick - concatenate looking for fields: `foo` and `bar` and then use `Contains` method:

```
var filters = new int[][] {
    new int[] { 2, 4 },
    new int[] { 5, 7 },
    new int[] { 9, 10 },
    new int[] { 11, 12 }                
};
var newFilter = filters.Select(x => x[0] + "-" + x[1]).ToList();

var answer = dbContext.myClass.Where(x => newFilter.Contains(x.foo + "-" + x.bar)).ToList();
```

Comment: This solution looks good. However I found a different solution which probably  has a better performance if *foo* or *bar* are indexes. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `values` is a jagged array, and that `myClass` is an `IEnumerable<T>` of an object that has `foo` and `bar` properties:

```
var query = myClass.Where(x => values.Any(y => x.foo == y[0] && x.bar == y[1]));
```

The inner `Any` statement, which is run against each object in `myClass`, looks for any "row" in `values` whose contents matches the `foo` and `bar` properties of `myClass`.  In essence, the `Any` clause iterates over each row in the table, while the `Where` clause iterates over (and filters) each object in `myClass`.

However, I don't know that it will be any more *efficient* than using a `Union`.

---

As noted in the comments, this method doesn't work with LINQ to Entities.  This could still be used in conjunction with Entity Framework by pulling all of the records from the database and filtering them in memory, but obviously this is not an efficient solution.

Comment: I am getting *The LINQ expression node type 'ArrayIndex' is not supported in LINQ to Entities* error.

Comment: After replacing the jagged array with an array of ForBarPair objects, I got *Unable to create a constant value of type 'FooBarPair'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.*

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var query = myClass.Where(x => x.Any(p => p[0] == foo && p[1] == bar));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take your integer set and make it into a map. Then test for `.Any` using LINQ.

```
    var map = new Dictionary<int, int>()
    {
        {2, 4},
        {5, 7},
        {9, 10},
        {11, 12}
    };

    var foo = 2;
    var bar = 4;

    var q = map.Any(kv => foo == kv.Key && bar == kv.Value);
```

Alternatively, you can take the list of int pairs and make them into a list of `Tuple<int, int>` and test for foo and bar like this:

```
    var q = listOfTuples.Any(tp => foo == tp.Item1 && bar == tp.Item2);
```

Main point here is that you need to take your "list of pairs of ints" and make a decision on how that information will be structured. Once you make that call, everything else falls into place. One step at a time, right?  :-)

Comment: Sorry, similar error than in the previous answer: *Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2*

Comment: Funny thing is, this works on my LinqPad. Obviously you have more code than I do.  ;-)

Comment: I think this is an EntityFramework limitation. Are you sure you are doing an EntityFramework query? The code that gives me the error is `var query = model.Set<MyClass>().Where(a => map.Any(kv => kv.Key == a.Foo && kv.Value == a.Bar))`

Comment: Ahh... I missed that! Yeah, you would have to force an early projection in order to make my code work then.

Comment: If you were using PetaPoco or Dapper, it would have been a simple issue of dynamically generating the `where` clause... just a matter of iterating the map and string formatting the foo and bar clauses. Too bad it's EF! Yet another reason for me to be glad I've left that behind.